# NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData is obsoleted in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nskeyedunarchiver

I tried to implement a fork of AwesomeCache that implements `unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData` in Swift 4:

```
if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) {
    do {
        possibleObject = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data as NSData) as? CacheObject
    }
    catch {}
}
```

But Xcode is angry at me now, and says:

```
'unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData' was obsoleted in Swift 4 (Foundation.NSKeyedUnarchiver)
```

Mean, imo, because it doesn't tell me what it's been replaced with (if anything?), and the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedunarchiver/2919664-unarchivetoplevelobjectwithdata) is rather... vacant.

So what do I use instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Agree with you, `NSData` is not `Data`, an improvement could be:

```
    if let nsData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) {
        do {
            let data = Data(referencing:nsData)
            possibleObject = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? CacheObject
        }
        catch {}
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Oh, silly me.

`NSData` is not `Data`

```
if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) {
    do {
        possibleObject = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data as Data) as? CacheObject
                                                                                //       ^
    }
    catch {}
}
```

...makes Xcode happy.